# Encontrar tabla en SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tengo el siguiete Query:

```
declare @busqueda as varchar(20)
set @busqueda = 'saldo_inventario'
select
  t.name as 'tabla',
  c.name as 'columna',
  ti.name as 'tipo',
  c.is_nullable as 'acepta datos nulos',
  c.max_length as 'largo máximo'
from
  sys.tables t left join
  sys.all_columns c on (c.object_id = t.object_id) left join
  sys.types ti on (c.system_type_id = ti.system_type_id)
where
  c.name like '%' + @busqueda + '%' or
  t.name like '%' + @busqueda + '%'
order by 'tabla'
```

El resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El detalle que tengo que al momento de buscar esas tablas en mi BDD no las encuentro y si le doy un `SELECT * FROM` me muestra lo siguiente:

> Invalid object name 'cosechas_empresarial_creditos'.

Comment: A que te refieres con que al momento de buscar esas tablas?, no lo ves en el SSMS?

Comment: Revisa el `owner` de las tablas `empresarial_creditos` y `empresarial_detalle`, puede que sea distinto con el cual te conectaste por eso no las ves o más bien no puedes acceder a ellas mediante un `select`

Comment: Exacto, incluso si trato de seleccionar esas tablas me muestra un mensaje indicando que el objeto es invalido

Comment: Agrega esto en tu consulta SQL SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS Esquema

Comment: Estas en la base de datos correcta, intenta poner el USE db_name;

Comment: Como te dice Egar, revisa el `Esquema ` que te retorna cada tabla, ya que luego deberías acceder mediante `select * from [esquema].[tabla]`

Answer (score 0):

Ya me dieron la respuesta en la parte de arriba, las tablas que estaba buscando tenían un `SCHEMA_ID` 5 el cual como nombre es `prueba` por lo cual mi consulta debería ser `SELECT * FROM prueba.empresarial_creditos` o `SLEECT * FROM prueba.empresarial_detalle` para obtener la información.

Comment: Si amigo por eso te comente que pongas esa linea el problema era ese saludos :D